# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

i got an error while im trying to execute query views in mysql version 5.7.19

Here is my query :

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`acc_webdev`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_dash_total` AS 
SELECT
  COUNT(0) AS `jumlah`,
  SYSDATE() AS `tanggal`
FROM `table_laporan`
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`table_laporan`.`dt_added`,'%d-%m-%Y') < (SYSDATE() + INTERVAL - (1)DAY))$$
```

and got this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$' at line 6

but in mysql 5.1.25, there's no error when i execute the query above

please help me out

Comment: Is that all there is? isn't it supposed to end with a semi colon?

Comment: what is your date format for `dt_added` ?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes, that's all... so should i replace '$$' with " ; " ?

Comment: @Irfan it's varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either prepend your DDL with `DELIMITER $$` or just change your delimiter to `;`.

Read more about [delimiters here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
CREATE VIEW `view_dash_total` AS 
SELECT
  COUNT(0) AS `jumlah`,
  SYSDATE() AS `tanggal`
FROM `table_laporan`
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`table_laporan`.`dt_added`,'%d-%m-%Y') < (SYSDATE() + INTERVAL - (1)DAY));
```